# Update TextBox column in DataGridView when change DataGridView ComboBox value

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, combobox

I have some problem when trying to work with **Data Gridview** in C# Windows Forms programming. I hope can get helps from Stack community. Below is my problem:
I have a table in my SQL Server Database

FID| FCode  | FName      |
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
1  | MAT001 | Material01 |
2  | MAT002 | Material02 |
3  | MAT003 | Material03 |
4  | MAT004 | Material04 |
5  | MAT005 | Material05 |
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

- And now in the Data Gridview of my application (C#) (My `DataGridView`
  has 2 columns, 1 is the Item Code, 1 is Item Name) , the Item Code
  column is a `ComboBox` control which will display the FCode value.
  I can connect to the data source and change the Gridview column to
  `ComboBox` type,then display it to the `DataGridView`. The **ValueMember** is FID , the **DisplayMember** is
  **FCode**.
- The remaining issue is: I'm trying to populate the Item Name (FName) to the second column,when I select an item in the `ComboBox`, the Item Name beside will
  update the name automatically. How can I solve this case? Please help! 
  Many thanks and warmest regards to our
  community for helping members.

Comment: Is this is WPF or WinForms thing?

Comment: This is just a windows form application. Thanks!

Comment: What do you bind the DataGridView to ? Is it a custom object, a DataTable ?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the information shortage, I bind the DataGridView to the DataTable in Business Logic Layer. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way of achieving this would be to handle the `DataTable.ColumnChanging` event for the table to which your DataGridView is bound.

Within this event handler, you will get a `DataColumnChangeEventArgs` parameter from which you can check which column is being changed. You can simply check if it's your Item Code column changing, and if so, lookup the value to be pushed to the corresponding Item Name column.

The `DataColumnChangeEventArgs` gives you the Column and also the Row that are being changed. From this you can determine where to push the Item Name.

Hope this helps

Comment: I got some solutions on the internet, the searching result give me that I can use the `EditingControlShowing` event of DataGridView and `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ComboBox` in the DataGridView. Would you mind giving me another suggestion for my case! Tks and best regards.

Comment: I can't comment on your other "solution". In any case, I always prefer working on the underlying data than on UI controls.